# How do I use the apache httpClient API?

Tags: java, html, httpclient

I'm basically trying to follow what everyone else is saying (http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) to do to use the Apache HttpClient (http://hc.apache.org/index.html) API to 'login' to a site. Everyone else is importing "org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient". Mine doesn't have that import, only stuff like "org.apache.http.client". Nowhere can I find the API which has their methods in it, so their code won't work for me. Does anyone know where I can get this different (external jar) file? If not, does anyone know how I can use the one I've got? Their tutorial fails for me. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the [dependencies](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/dependencies.html) link on the tutorial page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "**org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient**" is the 3.x (back when it was Jakarta commons) and is the tutorial that you are looking at. The "**org.apache.http.client**" stuff is the newer 4.x version (HTTP Components). Try this page: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/

From the apache HTTP Components page:

> Commons HttpClient 3.x codeline is at the end of life. All users of Commons HttpClient 3.x are strongly encouraged to upgrade to HttpClient 4.1.

Comment: Now If you could give me a method to submit a form (login to a site), with a given site, and login asp form, I'd be really happy ;) Can't make too much out of the thing you gave me